Prove that the incentral triangle determines the triangle
I would like to prove the incentral triangle determines the triangle.
This blogpost determines when the incentral triangle is isosceles.
This question proves when the reference triangle has an angle 120°, the incentral triangle has a right angle.
This similar question Prove that length of three bisectors determine triangle. has a nice proof by Brouwer fixed point theorem.

Suppose $\triangle ABC$ is the incentral triangle of some triangle, whose incenter has barycentric coordinates $(l:m:n)$ wrt $\triangle ABC$.
Using the method of this answer, $(l:m:n)$ should satisfy
$$l^2(c^2 m^2 + a^2 m n - b^2 m n - c^2 m n + b^2 n^2)\\
=m^2(c^2 l^2 - a^2 l n + b^2 l n - c^2 l n + a^2 n^2)\\ 
=n^2(b^2 l^2 - a^2 l m - b^2 l m + c^2 l m + a^2 m^2)$$
Eliminating $n$, we get a quartic equation in $x=l/m$
$$x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+s=0$$where$$p=\frac{a^6-2 a^4 b^2-3 a^4 c^2+a^2 b^4+2 a^2 b^2 c^2+3 a^2 c^4+b^4 c^2-c^6}{-a^4 b^2+2 a^2 b^4+2 a^2 b^2 c^2-b^6-b^4 c^2-b^2 c^4},\\q=\frac{2 a^6-2 a^4 b^2-2 a^4 c^2-2 a^2 b^4+2 a^2 b^2 c^2-2 a^2 c^4+2 b^6-2 b^4 c^2-2 b^2 c^4+2 c^6}{-a^4 b^2+2 a^2 b^4+2 a^2 b^2 c^2-b^6-b^4 c^2-b^2 c^4},\\r=\frac{a^4 b^2+a^4 c^2-2 a^2 b^4+2 a^2 b^2 c^2+b^6-3 b^4 c^2+3 b^2 c^4-c^6}{-a^4 b^2+2 a^2 b^4+2 a^2 b^2 c^2-b^6-b^4 c^2-b^2 c^4},\\s=\frac{-a^6+2 a^4 b^2-a^4 c^2-a^2 b^4+2 a^2 b^2 c^2-a^2 c^4}{-a^4 b^2+2 a^2 b^4+2 a^2 b^2 c^2-b^6-b^4 c^2-b^2 c^4}$$
By the result of this answer, this quartic equation has a real root iff
$$\Delta \leq 0\lor(8q-3 p^2\le0\land -3 p^4+16 p^2 q-16 p r-16 q^2+64 s \leq 0)\tag{*}$$
where $\Delta=-27 p^4 s^2 + 18 p^3 q r s - 4 p^3 r^3 - 4 p^2 q^3 s + p^2 q^2 r^2 + 144 p^2 q s^2 - 6 p^2 r^2 s - 80 p q^2 r s + 18 p q r^3 - 192 p r s^2 + 16 q^4 s - 4 q^3 r^2 - 128 q^2 s^2 + 144 q r^2 s - 27 r^4 + 256 s^3$ is the discriminant.
Substituting in $p,q,r,s$ we need to verify (*) for all $a,b,c$. But this involves large computation.

A nuance is that (*) cannot distinguish incenter with excenters, so the solutions for $(l:m:n)$ also includes the case when $\triangle ABC$ is the Cevian triangle of excenter, so we need a way to rule out the excenter case.

It can be right-angled when the reference triangle $ABC$ has an angle of 120 degrees.

@DuongNgo Thanks, I was wrong. I have corrected my calculation. I hope my new calculation is correct.

@hbghlyj Why did you think that "The shape of an incentral triangle is not arbitrary"?

So far, I don't know whether it is true or false as there has been no proof or counterexample. However I believe it is arbitrary, and there might be a point P such that it is the incenter of its anticevian triangle. I have no clue to search for this point in ETC. I will post a question on https://groups.io/g/euclid

I posted a question here. Waiting for responses.
